# jQuery selector with bitwise operations on attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some code:

```
var type    = li.attr('type');
$('tbody tr td a', table).each(function() {
 if ($(this).is('[type]') && $(this).attr('type') & type) {
   $(this).show();
  }
  else {
   $(this).hide();
 }
});
```

It works as expected but there are two issues:

1. Is it possible to make this functionality without each function? 
   `$('tbody tr td a[type&=' + type).show();` or something like that?
2. Another issue is that each iteration works very slow. I can notice
   delay for 300 objects while simple action for all elements in
   selector: $('tbody tr td a', table).show(); works pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use fitter it , example

```
 $.extend(  
     jQuery.expr[":"], {  
         istype: function(elem) {  
             return $(elem).attr('type');  
         }
     }  
 );  

 $("li:istype").hide();
```

But i need full of your html to give a fastest code , please give it for me

Comment: Here are links ( a ) elements in the table cells that have attribute 'type'. I need filter them by bitwise operation depending on what li was pressed. li also has 'type' attribute.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understood it , can u goto http://jsfiddle.net and give me a live example for a fastest code ; thanks u :)